# Sonarqube load settings from widget

Tags: java, widget, sonarqube

I have an custom plugin for SonarQube (6.1) and I'm trying to figure out how to add some sort of configuration interface.

The use case should be following:

- User configures settings of the plugin in SonarQube UI from the plugin's widget
- When the user runs the analysis (with the mentioned plugin) the behavior of the plugin will depend on the user settings

Is this use case possible? Can SonarQube load settings from widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to have a look at the PropertyDefinition extension point in SQ (https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/sonar-plugin-api/src/main/java/org/sonar/api/config/PropertyDefinition.java).

You won't get the ability to configure the property in plugin's widget but in SQ's admin page (or a project's admin page). This is the feature usually used to pass configuration to a plugin.